# Printk print twice: how to supress the one with prefix information?

Tags: linux, driver, device, printk

I am trying the linux device programming but run into a strange problem.  For all of my printk lines, it will always display twice on the console.

For example, here is my helloworld driver program:

```
#include <linux/init.h>
#include <linux/module.h>
#include <linux/kernel.h>
MODULE_LICENSE("Dual BSD/GPL");

static int hello_init(void) {
    printk("<1> Hello world!\n");
    return 0;
}

static void hello_exit(void) {
    printk("<1> Bye, cruel world\n");
}

module_init(hello_init);
module_exit(hello_exit);
```

Here is my make file:

```
ifneq ($(KERNELRELEASE),)
    obj-m := hello.o
else
    KERNELDIR := /gumstix/linux-2.6.21gum/
    PWD := $(shell pwd)
    ARCH := arm
    CROSS := arm-linux-

default:
    $(MAKE) -C $(KERNELDIR) M=$(PWD) ARCH=$(ARCH) CROSS_COMPILE=$(CROSS) modules

clean:
    $(MAKE) -C $(KERNELDIR) M=$(PWD) ARCH=$(ARCH) clean

endif
```

When I load the driver, it will show the message twice.  The second time will always give some annoying prefix information which I don't need!

```
# insmod hello.ko
Hello world!
# Oct 31 10:16:35 gumstix user.alert kernel:  Hello world!
```

And I tried changing the printk configuration, it will only supress the first message (see below). and 'dmesg -n 1' has the same result.

```
# echo 0       0       0      0 > /proc/sys/kernel/printk
# insmod hello.ko
# Oct 31 10:29:58 gumstix user.alert kernel:  Hello world!
```

Can any one tell me why this prefix information (timestamp + "gumstix user.alert kernel:") shows up all the time?  How to remove it if possible?  Many thanks.

Here below is a summary of my environment:

```
kernel: linux-2.6.21
qemu: QEMU PC emulator version 0.9.1
```

Comment: Maybe it is because you specify the information level to be an alert. Anyway, if you want to do so, use `KERN_ALERT "Hello world"` instead of `"<1> Hello world"`. This way what is intended is clearer.

Comment: Thanks Rerito.  I tried that also (ALERT, INFO, WARN, etc.), but still got the same problem :(